# Visual Studio 2022 Design Tab not showing interactive objects, only text

Tags: visual-studio-2022, design-view

I recently upgraded from VS 2019 to 2022.   I tried to mimic my installation  from 2019 to the 2022.   So far the only thing I seem to be missing is when I am editing a page that has controls on such as as LinqDataSource, GridView or even DropDownLists  I could go into The Design Tab and have "Task" windows pop up that would allow to edit/select certain attributes.   in 2019  I had  Design, Split and Source tabs and when I went to the Design tab I would have this feature available. (image 1)

[image: image 1 VS 2019]

But in 2022 I only have a Design and Split view but the Design view just shows me textual descriptions of the code/control.  (image 2 & 3)  What have not enables or installed to allow me to see these Task Views or should I be editing things in a different way?

[image: VS 2022 text instead of controls]
[image: VS 2022 code view with tabs]

Answer (score 0):

The difference you're seeing is the new [Web Live Preview](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/design-your-web-forms-apps-with-web-live-preview-in-visual-studio-2022/) feature in VS2022 - a replacement for the old WebForms designer.  It's an entirely new designer experience (the old designer is, um, ancient and not very maintainable with newer web technologies).

The issue you're seeing appears to be a bug; the WLP designer is trying to render design-time HTML from your control, and something in the .NET Framework control is choking.  Please file feedback using the VS Feedback tool in the IDE.